# HTML CSS | why are my pictures displayed one below the other?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i can't find the fault..

Code:

```
.gallery {
  background-color: #000000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin: 10px;
  max-width: 310px;
  min-width: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

When i change the position, the pictures lie on top of each other.

Comment: Most likely because the HTML element is a block level element. Add `display: inline-block` to you CSS.

Comment: @RandyCasburn You're the one! Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

your problem should be that the parent container of the gallery isn't big enough. Being that using "float: left", the elements that don't fit inside that parent container, will be displayed one below another.
Try enlarging the parent container to a width, in which you are sure the images will fit.